# document.body.removeEventListener removes ALL click event listeners (not the specified function) why?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
document.body.removeEventListener("click", delElm);
```

removes all "onclick" events for the entire page. why? Am I not clearly specifying what function I want removed from the document.body?

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='dynamicLinkCheckOutput'></div>";
var dynamicLinkCheckOutput = document.getElementById('dynamicLinkCheckOutput');

function delElm(e){
    var dynamicLinkCheckOutput = document.getElementById('dynamicLinkCheckOutput');        
       dynamicLinkCheckOutput.parentNode.removeChild(dynamicLinkCheckOutput);
    //document.body.removeEventListener("click", delElm); //moved for clairity
}
setTimeout(function(){
    dynamicLinkCheckOutput.onclick = function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", delElm);
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", delElm); //ALL click events from ALL elements have been removed the moment this line executes. 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> document.body.removeEventListener("click", delElm);
> ```
>
> removes all "onclick" events for the entire page

No, it doesn't. But this does:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='dynamicLinkCheckOutput'></div>";
```

Using `+=` on `innerHTML` forces the browser to:

- Spin through all of the elements inside `body` building an HTML string for them.
- Return that string to the JavaScript layer, which then adds on the string on the right-hand side.
- Parse the string assigned back to `innerHTML` by the JavaScript layer, wipe out all elements within `body` (thus losing their event handlers and most other state), and create *new*, replacement elements for them from the parsed HTML.

If you want to append to `body` (or any other element), don't use `innerHTML += x`, use:

- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

  ```
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div id='dynamicLinkCheckOutput'></div>");
  ```

  or
- [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

  ```
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "dynamicLinkCheckOutput";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  ```

  or
- Various other DOM methods. More to explore: [DOM on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: @Sam - A pleasure. Happy coding! :-)